# Changing Bootstrap's Default Modal Class

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I need to change Bootstrap's Javascript and CSS files in order to change the class name that is applied to the main containing div for modals.

Here is the default container:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

And here is how I'd like to change it:

```
<div class="MY-modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

I've tried running through the modal.js and modal.less files and changing all references to ".modal" to ".MY-modal" but I get the following error in the console: *Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment*.

Could anyone provide some insight in to exactly what lines I need to change in the JS file to make this work?

The reason I need to change this, is I am implementing Bootstrap in to an in-house CMS that already uses the class **.modal** for it's own modals, and this causes conflicts with Bootstrap.

Comment: I think you changed a little too much when editing modal.js - also this is a really bad practice. Why don't you just adapt the already existing modals? Or use the javascript api of bootstrap modal to call it like $('.MY-modal').modal(options)

Comment: Don't hack the core, dude! What happens when you (or, Zeus forbid, someone else) needs to update Bootstrap? Kaboom.

Comment: Unfortunitely, the nature of the CMS we need to use, uses inline editing for content. Therefore, the CSS of bootstrap conflicts with the functionality of the system. Modals seem to be the only feature that conflicts and we're going to be maintaining our own flavour of Bootstrap. All the changes we make will be logged, so future upgrades shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, creating a modifier class for base `.modal` (for example `.modal--custom`)

If you use sass it's simple as that:

```
$modal-name: 'modal';

.#{$modal-name} {
    &--custom {
        .#{$modal-name}-dialog {
            // some custom styling
        }
        .#{$modal-name}-footer {
            // some custom styling
        }
        .#{$modal-name}-body {
            // some custom styling
        }

    }
}
```

and then you apply both

```
<div class="modal modal--custom"></div>
```

A little more problematic is a modal backdrop. I used a little bit of a workaround for that one, which basically adds a custom class immediately after `.show()` method is called:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    const backdropClassName = 'modal-backdrop--custom';

    $(() => {
        $('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const $modalBackdrop = $('.modal-backdrop');
                if ($modalBackdrop.length > 0 && !$modalBackdrop.hasClass(backdropClassName)) {
                    $modalBackdrop.addClass(backdropClassName);
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```